# Run Jenkins build on push to random repository on Bitbucket

Tags: git, jenkins, build, bitbucket, webhooks

I've got many repositories hosted on Bitbucket which need to trigger builds in Jenkins. These repositories all need to be build roughly the same way. Based on the Bitbucket payload I'd like to clone the pushed repository with a small script and build that specific project. I'll be needing - at least - the **repo URL** and the **branch**. This is what I tried thus far.

## Attempt #1

Using the [Bitbucket plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin). This will only trigger when the SCM URL will loosely match, which will never be the case since I do not know the repository URL on forehand and therefor this attempt fails to suit my use case.

## Attempt #2

Using the built-in Remote trigger; this actually works a lot better, since I'm able to run the build from any repository with the correct token. Though, this attempt fails since I'm not able to retrieve the payload which Bitbucket posts to Jenkins. I've been able to confirm that the payload is not passed through by running `printenv` in the build, which does not show the payload.

## Goals

1. How do I trigger my build from a **unknown** Bitbucket repository URL?
2. How do I retrieve the Payload which has been delivered by the [Bitbucket Push](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/event-payloads-740262817.html#EventPayloads-Push) event?

I'm using Jenkins 2.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I concluded my use-case was too specific to use a out-of-the-box solution. Therefor, I developed a small Node.js service which acts as a small proxy server. It receives the payload from Bitbucket, then transforms that data before sending it through to Jenkins. Works like a charm.